# how to get value from response from Microsoft cogntive services

Tags: arrays, json

I am making a http request to "Microsoft cogntive services" ; and I am getting a proper answer, but I am failing to get the value out of the response.

Here is my script:

```
'use strict';

const request = require('request');

// Replace <Subscription Key> with your valid subscription key. const subscriptionKey = 'xyz'; // here my API key

// You must use the same location in your REST call as you used to get your // subscription keys. For example, if you got your subscription keys from // westus, replace "westcentralus" in the URL below with "westus". const uriBase = 'https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect';

const imageUrl =
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534559529872-1a83a6cbc03d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=56820e7b0db7b8a7f10804cd157f61ef&w=1000&q=80'
    // Request parameters. const params = {
    'returnFaceId': 'true',
    'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
    'returnFaceAttributes': 'age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,' +
        'emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise' };

const options = {
    uri: uriBase,
    qs: params,    //  json: true, // dies nachtäglich eingefügt ev. löschen
    body: '{"url": ' + '"' + imageUrl + '"}',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : subscriptionKey
    } };

request.post(options, (error, response, body) => {   if (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
    return;   }   let jsonResponse = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body), null, '  ');   console.log('JSON Response\n');   console.log(jsonResponse); });
```

and here the response that I get:

```
[    {
      "faceId":"f469c0b3-fbb8-4238-a52a-54fd515a2bca",
      "faceRectangle":{
         "top":327,
         "left":253,
         "width":426,
         "height":426
      },
      "faceAttributes":{
         "smile":0.005,
         "headPose":{
            "pitch":0,
            "roll":0.7,
            "yaw":-4.4
         },
         "gender":"female",
         "age":23,
         "facialHair":{
            "moustache":0,
            "beard":0,
            "sideburns":0
         },
         "glasses":"NoGlasses",
         "emotion":{
            "anger":0,
            "contempt":0,
            "disgust":0,
            "fear":0,
            "happiness":0.005,
            "neutral":0.994,
            "sadness":0.001,
            "surprise":0
         },
         "blur":{
            "blurLevel":"low",
            "value":0
         },
         "exposure":{
            "exposureLevel":"goodExposure",
            "value":0.64
         },
         "noise":{
            "noiseLevel":"low",
            "value":0
         },
         "makeup":{
            "eyeMakeup":true,
            "lipMakeup":true
         },
         "accessories":[

         ],
         "occlusion":{
            "foreheadOccluded":false,
            "eyeOccluded":false,
            "mouthOccluded":false
         },
         "hair":{
            "bald":0.02,
            "invisible":false,
            "hairColor":[
               {
                  "color":"blond",
                  "confidence":0.99
               },
               {
                  "color":"gray",
                  "confidence":0.74
               },
               {
                  "color":"other",
                  "confidence":0.35
               },
               {
                  "color":"brown",
                  "confidence":0.31
               },
               {
                  "color":"red",
                  "confidence":0.15
               },
               {
                  "color":"black",
                  "confidence":0.06
               }
            ]
         }
      }    } ]
```

Now would I would like to do it to get the value for "faceID" or faceAttributes.gender or faceAttributes.age

I have tried that with the following commands, but I always get the following errors.

i.e.

```
console.log(jsonResponse.faceId);
```

log-message:

> script.js.facedetect_node: undefined

i.e.

```
console.log(jsonResponse.faceId[0]);
```

log-message:

> uncaught exception: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

i.e.

```
console.log(jsonResponse.faceAttributes[0]);
```

i.e.

```
console.log(jsonResponse.faceAttributes.age[0]);
```

log-message

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

I guess you have already seen that I am quite a newbie - for this reason I would highly appreciate if you have an idea how I can get the mentioned values out of this json.

cu
schroedinger

Comment: Please reformat your question properly. Something about your response doesn't look right (looks lie there is one too many } at the end) but it is tough to tell because you broke it up in two different places.

Comment: hi,

here is a new response. (its a bit shorter this time, because requested this time less "faceattributes":

[{
  "faceId": "72339898-6e2b-4e75-8b7b-4bf105422213",
  "faceRectangle": {
    "top": 327,
    "left": 253,
    "width": 426,
    "height": 426
  },
  "faceAttributes": {
    "age": 23.0
  }
}]

Comment: Your problem is with how you are calling the response after you stringify and parse it. I can't recreate your error because you didn't put a complete example in your question. What happens if you try console.log(response) in your request.post function?

Comment: Hi ecg8, 
thank you for your help.

I think I would solve the problem on my own by doing the following:

var persons = JSON.parse(body);
    if (persons.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
  
  var person = persons[0]; // 1. Objekt auf body ist Person
  var faceId2 = person.faceId; // faceId2 ist value von hochgeladenen gesicht

by doing so I got the value of